# PDO query with session doesn't return anything

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm starting to learn `PDO` and while doing this decided to rewrite my old `mysql_*` code. So I have a login form which according to userlevel redirects to different locations. This is done (`I think since I can login correctly`). Next when redirects me I have query which depending of userlevel show some result from database. The problem is that it doesn't return anything and there are no errors in the logfile. This is my login. Am I doing it correctly?

```
session_start();
if(isSet($_POST['submit'])) {
include 'misc/database.inc.php';
$pdo = Database::connect();

$username=$_POST['username']; 
$password=sha1($_POST['password']); 

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username AND password = :password");

    $stmt->bindParam(':username', $username);
    $stmt->bindParam(':password', $password);

    $stmt->execute();

    $res  = $stmt -> fetch();

if ($res['userlevel'] == 1)
{
    // Save type and other information in Session for future use.
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        $_SESSION['password'] = $password;
        $_SESSION['userlevel'] = $userlevel;

    header( "location: admins/main.php");   
}
elseif ( $res['userlevel'] >= 4 ) 
{
        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $id; 
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        $_SESSION['password'] = $password;
        $_SESSION['userlevel'] = $userlevel;
        $_SESSION['firstname'] = $firstname;
        $_SESSION['lastname'] = $lastname;
        $_SESSION['user_image'] = $user_image;
        $_SESSION['email'] = $email;    
        header('Location: users/main.php');
}
else 
{
    header("location: index.php");
}
// Closing MySQL database connection 
$pdo = null;
} else {
```

And this is the query which I want to perform in `main.php` when login according to userlevel

```
<?php
include '../misc/database.inc.php';
$pdo = Database::connect();
$q = "SELECT * FROM ras AS r 
    LEFT JOIN user_ras AS r2u ON r.userlevel = r2u.ras_userlevel
    LEFT JOIN users AS u ON r2u.user_userlevel = u.userlevel where menu = '".$_SESSION['userlevel']."'";

foreach($pdo->query($q) as $res)
{
    echo '<a href="users/ras.php?rest_id='. $res['ras_id'] .'">'.$res['name'].'</a>';

 }
 Database::disconnect();
 ?>
```

As I said I'm completely new to PDO so please bear with me and if you can help me. Thank you.

**Update - database.inc.php**

```
<?php
class Database
{
private static $dbName = 'dbname' ;
private static $dbHost = 'localhost' ;
private static $dbUsername = 'user';
private static $dbUserPassword = 'pass';

private static $cont  = null;

public function __construct() {
    die('Init function is not allowed');
}

public static function connect()
{
   // One connection through whole application
   if ( null == self::$cont )
   {     
    try
    {
      self::$cont =  new PDO( "mysql:host=".self::$dbHost.";"."dbname=".self::$dbName, self::$dbUsername, self::$dbUserPassword); 
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
      die($e->getMessage()); 
    }
   }
   return self::$cont;
}

public static function disconnect()
{
    self::$cont = null;
}
}
?>
```

Comment: `session_start();` needs to be inside all files using sessions.

Comment: Yes, I've have it inside main.php. In fact when I log whit some user I can see his username `<?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>` so the session is work. But query doesn't.

Comment: `r2u.user_userlevel` you sure you didn't mean `r2u.userlevel`? Hard to say, joins aren't something I'm good at. add `$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` right after the connection is opened.

Comment: Yes, this query with `mysql_*` is working. I've also just tried `select * from res` and also didn't return results which is strange.

Comment: If you say it's working with `mysql_*` and not PDO; is your DB connection in fact PDO? Plus, SQL is standard, only the APIs change. What's different from both APIs in the query?

Comment: In my *edited* comment above, said to add `$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` right after the connection is opened. See if that yields any errors. Also  error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.

Comment: No, nothing. `Undefined $res` on `if($res){}` but nothing else

Comment: Your query failed then. See what you can pull from the manual on fetch() http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php - Plus, it's suggested to add `exit;` after each header.

Comment: @Fred-ii-, thank's for your help also!

Comment: You're welcome Jason, glad to see you've found a solution, *cheers*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

where are the variables defined that you are assigning to session  `$id, $userlevel, $firstname, $lastname, $user_image, $email` ?
They are undefined at this point:

```
    $_SESSION['user_id']   = $id; 
    $_SESSION['userlevel'] = $userlevel;
    $_SESSION['firstname'] = $firstname;
    $_SESSION['lastname']  = $lastname;
    $_SESSION['user_image']= $user_image;
    $_SESSION['email']     = $email;
```

I think what you need is this

```
session_start();
if(isSet($_POST['submit'])) {
include 'misc/database.inc.php';
$pdo = Database::connect();

$username=$_POST['username']; 
$password=sha1($_POST['password']); 

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username AND password = :password");

    $stmt->bindParam(':username', $username);
    $stmt->bindParam(':password', $password);

    $stmt->execute();

    $res  = $stmt -> fetch();

if ($res['userlevel'] == 1)
{
    // Save type and other information in Session for future use.
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        $_SESSION['password'] = $password;
        $_SESSION['userlevel'] = $res['userlevel'];

    header( "location: admins/main.php");   
}
elseif ( $res['userlevel'] >= 4 ) 
{
        $_SESSION['user_id']   = $res['id'];
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        $_SESSION['password'] = $password;  
        $_SESSION['userlevel'] = $res['userlevel'];
        $_SESSION['firstname'] = $res['firstname'];
        $_SESSION['lastname']  = $res['lastname'];
        $_SESSION['user_image']= $res['user_image'];
        $_SESSION['email']     = $res['email']; 
        header('Location: users/main.php');
}
else 
{
    header("location: index.php");
}
}
```

Comment: I get error like that -> `PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function bindParam() on a non-object`

Comment: I updated the full block..try it.. that should work perfectly

Answer (score 1):

Can you echo the contents of `$res`?
such as:

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($res);
echo "<pre>";
```

and see what the result is, maybe your array doesn't know the value of `$res['userlevel']`, your array might be accessed as `$res[0]['userlevel']` or something like that.

Let me know if it works

Comment: print_r($res) return nothing. Just empty space on the page.

Comment: Then your $res array is empty that is why it not working. Is the password stored as sha1 in the database?

Comment: Your select statement isn't returning anything, you can make a test to compare the sha1($_POST['password']) with the one stored in the database, I'm guessing that is where the select statement doesn't return a matching username and password

Comment: But I have logged in successfully. If the password is wrong I can't login?

Comment: According to your code if the password is wrong you send the user to header("location: index.php"); so none of the code after $res  = $stmt -> fetch(); will be executed

Comment: Yes, but I logging in. As I said I'm redirected to main.php and whit $_SESSION['username'] I can see username displayed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66287/discussion-between-azael-and-jason-paddle).

Answer (score 1):

You should check to see if you have a result set.

```
    if ($res) {

    foreach($pdo->query($q) as $res)
    {
        echo '<a href="users/ras.php?rest_id='. $res['ras_id'] .'">'.$res['name'].'</a>';

     }
    } else {
    echo '<p>no result</p>';
   }
```